# advantages of using return vs this

Tags: javascript

This is a simple class that looks familiar.

```
var Cat = function () {
    this.speak = function() {
        return "meow";
    };
};
```

But, I often see this written that way

```
var Dog = function() {
    var api = {};
    api.speak = function() {
        return "bark";
    };
    return api;
};
```

They both are instantiated and used the same way.

```
var garfield = new Cat();
console.log(garfield.speak());

var odie = new Dog();
console.log(odie.speak());
```

So, what is the advantages of using the Dog way ?

Comment: The result is exactly same. Its not about advantages... its about use-case and choice of design pattern.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing. you are doing it the wrong way in both cases.

What happens now is that everytime an object gets instantiated a variable Object is added and each object is instantiated with its own methods.

In the Dog way you are adding a Function Object within an Object to a variable. Even more memory intensive.

The best way to do this is as following, which makes sure all Dogs will have the same speak function, which costs less memory

```
function Dog(bark) {
    this.bark = bark;
}
Dog.prototype.speak = function() {
   console.log(this.bark);
}

var odie = new Dog("yip yip");
var bully = new Dog("WOOF!");
odie.speak();
bully.speak();
```

This way the speak function takes up only one piece of memory for both dogs. Both use the exact same function to speak.
in your memory you have now:

- odie (Dog)
- bully (Dog)
- speak (Function)

In your example both dogs would have

- odie (Dog)
- bully (Dog)
- odie.speak (Function)
- bully.speak (Function)

with two dogs the memory issue might be neglible. But if you have 10.000 dogs, it becomes an issue.